# Math mode in Springer Bibliography doesn't run

Tags: springernature

I would like to know how to use mathmode in Springer Nature bibliography.

This is an excerpt from the main file:

```
\begin{document}
Cite \cite{bib12}
\end{document}
```

This is an excerpt from the bib file:

```
@article{bib12, 
   author  = "R. W. Gosper",
   title   = "$\int_{\frac{m}{4}}^{\frac{n}{4}}$, Special
              functions, $q$-series and related topics",
   journal = "The Fields Institute Communications",
   volume  = "14",
   year    = "1997",
   pages   = "71--76"
}
```

After running PdFLaTeX + Bibtex + PdFLaTeX + PdFLaTeX, the output of the BBL is just 0kb.

Comment: Please confirm that you employ the `sn-jnl` document class and the `sn-mathphys` bibliography style.

Answer (score 5):

"Springer Nature" provides several bibliography styles. Assuming you employ the `sn-jnl` document class and `sn-mathphys` bibliography style, the first directive in the tex file should be

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
```

This setup assures that the `natbib` citation management package is loaded with options appropriate for Math and Physical Sciences. For more information on this subject, see section 8.3, "References", of the user guide of the `sn-jnl` distribution. (The file name of the user guide is "user-manual.pdf".)

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{bib12, 
   author  = "R. W. Gosper",
   title   = "$\int_{u}^{v}$, Special functions, $q$-series 
              and related topics",
   journal = "The Fields Institute Communications",
   volume  = "14",
   year    = "1997",
   pages   = "71--76"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Cite \cite{bib12}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I shall try it out. Thanks

Comment: What pattern do I use to run it after including it? Using the pattern PdFLaTeX + Bibtex + PdFLaTeX + PdFLaTeX gives 0 kb BBL for my Main bibliography.

Comment: @AbdulhafeezAyindeAbdulsalam - Not sure I understand your question, "what pattern do I use to run it"? Have you made sure that the `\cite` and `\bibliography` directives have the correct arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to open the BBL file with TeXworks and I just placed the Mathematical expression where I wanted it. The output was as I wanted it.

Comment: Which then is overwritten next time someone runs `bibtex`